# Access android "device only" GPS on Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, geolocation, gps

I'm developing an GPS app on Epson Moverio, but since Moverio has only "Device only" GPS option activated, the standard unity C# code to access GPS doesn't work. Infact the app hangs on "LocationServiceStatus.Initializing", I suppose that's why the code "Input.location.Start();" try to access the "high Precision" GPS option, where the Android system mix the GPS sensor with network signals from Wi-fi, Cellular and Bluetooth.

Can anyone know how to access the "Device only" GPS option from Unity? I think it's possible in Android Studio, but I haven't found anything in Unity.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may be taking a long time the first time you are trying to get a GPS signal.  Documentation says you should make sure you are outside away from tall building to make sure the device can get a good look at a number of satellites.  go outside for 20 minutes and see if you can get a lock on a signal.